# Regex - negative Negative Lookbehind with br

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

i have a string:

```
var a = '<<<<<<<br>>>>>>>>'
```

I want to replace: `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`, but I don't want to replace `<>` if it is the `<br>` tag. So, I'm doing this

```
a.replace(/<(?!br>)/g, '&lt;').replace(/>(?<!<br)/g, '&gt;')
```

first replace is working, but the second is not.

Comment: For the general case, I think you might need a parser to handle this.

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/pwh3ht1t/, it might you give an idea how to solve this with 1 regex replace call.

Comment: You could just replace `<+` with `&lt;` and `>+` with `&gt;` which would be the simplest way I can see that happening with a regex.

Comment: Actually, I read that question wrong. Now I wonder if that's _really_ what you want to do or is that an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't support lookbehinds so your expression is not valid.

For opening braces:

```
<(?!\/?\w)
```

For closing braces:

```
\B>
```

*`\B` denotes a non-word boundary.*

JS:

```
> a.replace(/<(?!\/?\w)/g, '&lt;').replace(/\B>/g, '&gt;')
< "&lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;<br>&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;"
```